# Series of nested normal subgroup (composition series) induces a sequence of quotient groups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

In Group theory in a nutshell by A. Zee on pg. 66 he introduces sequences of nested normal subgroups:

$G \rhd H_1 \rhd H_2 \rhd \dots \rhd H_k \rhd I$.

Then he says that this induces a sequence of quotient groups:

$G/
H_1 \supset H_1/H_2 \supset H_2/H_3 \supset \dots \supset H_k$.

Why is this true? And how to interpret this sequence of quotient groups? At first sight it seems strange, as $G/H_1$ consists of cosets of $H_1$ and $H_1/H_2$ consists of cosets of $H_2$, it seems $H_1/H_2$ cannot be a subset of $G/H_1$.

**Edit** There is an [errata](https://www.kitp.ucsb.edu/zee/books/group-theory-nutshell-physicists/errata-and-addenda-group-theory-nutshell-physicists) available for this statement, it says $H_k$ in the second line should be replaced by $H_{k-1}/H_k$. This doesn't change my question.

Comment: This is not true, e.g. all of those groups could be cyclic groups of distinct prime orders.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan do you mean the groups in the first statement, or the quotient groups in the second statement?

Comment: The quotient groups. Generally speaking you should not trust physicists to teach you group theory, they're very sloppy about a lot of things.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That last remark is a great one, LOL! Still, most of the physicists are actually very good mathematicians ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true, as pointed out in a comment. What is probably meant is that

> this induces a sequence of quotient groups: $G/H_1$, $H_1/H_2$, $H_2/H_3$, $\ldots$, $H_{k-1}/H_k$, $H_k/I$.

Here $H_k/I \cong H_k$, so writing

> $G/H_1$, $H_1/H_2$, $H_2/H_3$, $\ldots$, $H_{k-1}/H_k$, $H_k$

or

> $G/H_1$, $H_1/H_2$, $H_2/H_3$, $\ldots$, $H_k$

would also be fine.

Comment: To complete the answer, could you make the counter example precise? What groups are G, H_1, H_2?

Comment: Take for example $G = C_p \times C_q$ for different primes $p$ and $q$. Let $H_1$ be the $C_p$ factor and $H_2 = I$, for example. Then $G/H_1 \cong C_q$ does not contain a copy of $H_1/H_2 \cong C_p$. So the inclusion $G/
H_1 \supset H_1/H_2$ written in the book makes no sense.